# Which chart framework is used on findthebest.com

Tags: javascript, html, graph, charts

I have been looking into the beautiful charts and graphs on http://smartphones.findthebest.com/

I am just curious which framework these guys used. If they created their own, is there any similar opensource framework available for these type of graphs and charts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for asking- your question is very flattering. We actually build all our visualizations mostly from scratch, since we don't want to deal with the overhead of external libraries and we have very specific needs. You can learn D3.js and do pretty much anything in terms of visualizations.

Good Luck!